# Parsing HTML form to JSON

Tags: jquery, html, json

I'm struggling to summarise an HTML form to JSON. I don't want the values that are disabled, since I am only interested in times that are available.

```js
console.log($(".venue input:enabled"))

// Ideally it could be in a JSON object like: 
// { 2: [ "07:00AM", "01:00PM", "02:00PM"], ... }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="venue">
    <h4>Court 2</h4>
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="timeslots[]" id="534584">
            <label for="534584">07:00 AM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>08:00 AM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>09:00 AM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>10:00 AM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>11:00 AM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>12:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="timeslots[]" id="534590">
            <label for="534590">01:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="timeslots[]" id="534591">
            <label for="534591">02:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>03:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>04:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>05:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>06:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>07:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>08:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>09:00 PM</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="venue">
    <h4>Court 3</h4>
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="timeslots[]" id="534584" disabled>
            <label for="534584">07:00 AM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>08:00 AM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>09:00 AM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>10:00 AM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>11:00 AM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>12:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="timeslots[]" id="534590">
            <label for="534590">01:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="timeslots[]" id="534591">
            <label for="534591">02:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>03:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>04:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>05:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>06:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>07:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>08:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>09:00 PM</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Stringify:

```
JSON.stringify([1, 'false', false]); // '[1,"false",false]'
```

Not sure if that's what you want to do.

more info about stringify [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but are you looking for this.

```js
var times = {};
$('.venue').each(function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  var timeLabel = $this.find('input:enabled').next();
  var timeArray = [];
  timeLabel.each(function() {
    timeArray.push($(this).text());
  })
  times[e + 1] = timeArray;
})
times = JSON.stringify(times);
console.log(times);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="venue">
    <h4>Court 2</h4>
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="timeslots[]" id="534584">
            <label for="534584">07:00 AM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>08:00 AM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>09:00 AM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>10:00 AM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>11:00 AM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>12:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="timeslots[]" id="534590">
            <label for="534590">01:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="timeslots[]" id="534591">
            <label for="534591">02:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>03:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>04:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>05:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>06:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>07:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>08:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>09:00 PM</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="venue">
    <h4>Court 3</h4>
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="timeslots[]" id="534584" disabled>
            <label for="534584">07:00 AM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>08:00 AM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>09:00 AM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>10:00 AM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>11:00 AM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>12:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="timeslots[]" id="534590">
            <label for="534590">01:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="timeslots[]" id="534591">
            <label for="534591">02:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>03:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>04:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>05:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>06:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>07:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>08:00 PM</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="">
            <label>09:00 PM</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the HTML, here you have an option...

```
var myJson = {};

$('div.venue').each(function() {
    var hours = [];
    var courtno = $(this).find('h4').text().split(' ')[1];

    $(this).find('input:enabled').each(function() {
        hours.push($(this).next('label').text());
    });

    myJson[courtno] = hours;
});
```

... but if you can, I would add a `data-courtno` to the venue div to indicate the parameter independently of the text you want to use in the h4. So, first adding...

```
<div class="venue" data-court="2">
    <h4>Court 2</h4>
...
<div class="venue" data-court="3">
    <h4>Court 3</h4>
...
```

... and the jquery would be...

```
var myJson = {};

$('div.venue').each(function() {
    var hours = [];

    $(this).find('input:enabled').each(function() {
        hours.push($(this).next('label').text());
    });

    myJson[$(this).data('court')] = hours;
});
```